# How to add plotOptions[] dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

In an Angular-8 project I want to display a dotted line running through the anomalies points I get from the backend dynamically & display it with different colors based on criticality . As of now I am only able to do so by hard-coding the values in plotOptions[], but I am not able to put them dynamically as plotOptions[] gives syntax error on doing do. Is there any other way to plot it.

Below is the stackbliz link for the same :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-kpaxpk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it dynamically, there are a few steps which you need to fallow:

1. Create the reference to the chart by using the chart callback function

```
chartCallback: Highcharts.ChartCallbackFunction = chart => {
    this.chartRef = chart;
};
```

2. Add `addPlotLines` method to the App and invoke that function in the chart load event.
3. In the `addPlotLines` method use reference and the axis `update` method add the plot lines. You might add some conditions here or loop through the data in a search for some points.

**API:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update 
**Demo:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-2o9wdh